# Hibernate n select issue with bidirectional same entity relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have **Item.java** entity with below properties

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="kitItem", fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
private Set<KitItemDetails> kitItemDetails = new HashSet<KitItemDetails>(0);

.... Other properties with getter and setter
```

I have **KitItemDetails.java** entity with below properties

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
private Item kitItem;
```

In my DAO access class we are using below query to fetch all items with other related attributes as EAGER

```
List<Item> items = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Item.class).addOrder(Order.asc("itemOrder"))
                .list();
```

But for this its firing n select queries to fecth item details as below

```
select kititemdet0_.kitItem_id as kitItem_2_9_0_, kititemdet0_.id as id1_12_0_, kititemdet0_.id as id1_12_1_, kititemdet0_.kitItem_id as kitItem_2_12_1_, kititemdet0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID3_12_1_, item1_.id as id1_9_2_, item1_.BAR_CODE as BAR_CODE2_9_2_, item1_.COLOR_CODE as COLOR_CO3_9_2_, item1_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIV4_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID as ITEM_CA14_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_CODE as ITEM_COD5_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_DISP_NAME as ITEM_DIS6_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_IMAGE as ITEM_IMA7_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_NAME as ITEM_NAM8_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_ORDER as ITEM_ORD9_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_PRICE as ITEM_PR10_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_PRICE_WITH_TAX as ITEM_PR11_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY_ID as ITEM_SU15_9_2_, item1_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TY12_9_2_, item1_.TAX_ID as TAX_ID16_9_2_, item1_.TAX_CODE as TAX_COD13_9_2_, itemcatego2_.id as id1_10_3_, itemcatego2_.COLOR_CODE as COLOR_CO2_10_3_, itemcatego2_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIV3_10_3_, itemcatego2_.ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME as ITEM_CAT4_10_3_, itemcatego2_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION6_10_3_, itemcatego2_.PRINTER_NAME as PRINTER_5_10_3_, itemsubcat3_.id as id1_11_4_, itemsubcat3_.COLOR_CODE as COLOR_CO2_11_4_, itemsubcat3_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIV3_11_4_, itemsubcat3_.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID as ITEM_CAT5_11_4_, itemsubcat3_.ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY_NAME as ITEM_SUB4_11_4_, tax4_.id as id1_21_5_, tax4_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIV2_21_5_, tax4_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION6_21_5_, tax4_.TAX_CODE as TAX_CODE3_21_5_, tax4_.TAX_NAME as TAX_NAME4_21_5_, tax4_.TAX_PER as TAX_PER5_21_5_ from KIT_ITEM_DETAILS kititemdet0_ inner join ITEM item1_ on kititemdet0_.ITEM_ID=item1_.id left outer join ITEM_CATEGORY itemcatego2_ on item1_.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID=itemcatego2_.id left outer join ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY itemsubcat3_ on item1_.ITEM_SUB_CATEGORY_ID=itemsubcat3_.id left outer join TAX tax4_ on item1_.TAX_ID=tax4_.id where kititemdet0_.kitItem_id=?
```

I tried with mappedBy, JoinColumn, JoinType, FetchMode, etc but did not worked out, what could be the issue ?

Comment: is `itemOrder` a property of `Item` class?

Comment: try this List<Item> items = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Item.class).setFetchMode("kitItemDetails", FetchMode.JOIN).addOrder(Order.asc("itemOrder"))
                .list();

Comment: @chsdk - yes itemOrder is a property of Item class

Comment: @MaximTulupov - Tried your suggestion, but did not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In general, having a relation set as EAGER does result in the "N select queries" problem when using criteria queries. You can overcome this by explicitly instructing Hibernate to do a fetch join. See [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-basics) for more details.

The documentation contains an example very similar to your scenario (tweaked to use your class names):

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Item> query = builder.createQuery( Item.class );
Root<Item> root = query.from( Item.class );
root.fetch( "kitItemDetails", JoinType.LEFT);
query.select(root).where(
   builder.and(
     builder.equal(root.get("foo"), foo),
     builder.equal(root.get("bar"), bar)
  )
);
Item item = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getSingleResult();
// Alternatively, .getResultList() to return List<Item>
```

`@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` will not work in your case because, as the documentation goes on to state in its example for `FetchMode.JOIN`:

> The reason why we are not using a JPQL query to fetch multiple Department entities is because the FetchMode.JOIN strategy would be overridden by the query fetching directive.